# Android - Custom Layout getting messed up inside ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm making an app that'll perform quadratic calculations using the quadratic formula. In order to show the steps for solving the equation, I'm using a `ListView` with each step as a `ListView` item. But, the custom layout that I've created for displaying the equation as row in the `ListView` is geting completely messed up upon running the application.

Here's what it should look like:
[image: layout]

and, here's what it's ACTUALLY looking like:
[image: device screen]

I just can't figure out what's wrong with, I've tried every possible solution found on the internet.

Here's my custom layout's xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/line"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="or,"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_equation_deno"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/main_equation_num"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-b ± √(b - 4ac)"
    android:id="@+id/main_equation_num"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2a"
    android:id="@+id/main_equation_deno"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's my list adapter:

```
public class StepListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Step> {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Step> mSteps = new ArrayList<Step>();

public StepListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Step> steps) {
    super(context, 0, steps);

    this.mContext = context;
    this.mSteps = steps;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_row, parent, false);

        TextView main_num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_equation_num);
        TextView main_deno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_equation_deno);

        main_num.setText(mSteps.get(position).getNum());
        main_deno.setText(mSteps.get(position).getDeno());

    return view;
    }
}
```

Any help regarding this issue shall be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Wherever you do so: `android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"` (mind the **+**!) you create a **new id**. The correct way to reference an **existing** id is `android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"` (**no plus sign**). This is why you declare this `android:id="@+id/imageView2"` **before** all other Views.

Comment: But, I didn't do that. The Graphical editor of Android Studio did it!

Comment: Android Studio has still MUCH to learn from Eclipse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_equation_num"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-b ± √(b - 4ac)"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/square"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="or,"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_equation_deno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="2a"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have made some changes in your xml just copy paste this xml.

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Try and let me know is it helpful to you.

Comment: You are introducing **unnecessary extra level nesting**.

Comment: @Der Golem, i respect your query regarding this, that i am introducing unnecessary nesting in layout.And somehow it helps swap  it would be great for me.

Comment: @AR See my answer. It's all done by using the **relativity** of the RelativeLayout's children.

Comment: @Swap But it is **sub-optimal**.

Comment: @DerGolem Your layout shrinks and gives almost the same result as mine. This is the only option I'm left with! Your layout displays perfectly when viewed independently as an `Activity`, but I need to put it in a `ListView` and that's where, due to some reason or other, it gets shrinked!

Comment: @Swap When put in a ListView, for some reasons, `match_parent` won't work. The row (RelativeLayout) height has to be a fixed value in dp, I.e.: `android:layout_height="320dp"`. Mistery.

Comment: @DerGolem Ya....I was thinking of doing that too... I'll try and tell you the the results soon...

Answer (score 1):

You might try to inflate row in different way:

> View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.step_row, null);

Or try to set min row height.
**EDIT:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="400dp">
...
```